# Page Object model in Leanft - Initialize elements

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects, leanft

I use TestNG in LeanFT. I created separated classes for pages and identified objects as it shown in code snippet below:

```
public class HomePage {
    private Browser browser;

    public HomePage(Browser browser) throws GeneralLeanFtException {
        this.browser = browser;
    }

    Button sendButton = browser.describe(Button.class, new ButtonDescription.Builder()
```

I can't initialize web elements in test class, failed to use `PageFactory`, because got `NullPointerException`.

```
PageFactory.initElements(browser, page);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This project contains template to work with LeanFT and TestNG: 
https://github.com/kohli-harshit/leanft-testng-template

```
LeanFT SDK and Report initialization
Logging with Log4J
Utils to Read from Properties File
Utils to Create Data Driven Tests from CSV Data
TestNG listeners used
```